# How to switch css file when using Webpack to load css?

Tags: css, gulp, webpack

I use gulp to compile my sass file to css files, and reference the css file in my html. The project support theme switch. For example, I have 3 css theme files:

- `red.css`
- `yellow.css`
- `blue.css`

I can currently switch the theme css like this:

```
var styleDom = $('#theme-style');
var newHref = 'styles/themes/' + themeName + '.css';
if (styleDom.attr('href') !== newHref) {
   styleDom.attr('href', newHref);
}
```

Now I want to use webpack to load the css file.

```
require('styles/themes/red.css');
```

It seems work well, but I cannot find a way to switch the theme css file now, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you need to switch runtime or is the result going to be unchanged once included to the build?

Comment: @bebraw, I need to switch css at rumtime.

Comment: Webpack is useless once you need to go beyond the typical boiler plate config. I have been struggling with this same concept for a couple days now.

Comment: You can check changing css themes in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270362/css-modules-and-multiple-layouts-themes/38315529#38315529 There is solution for static and chunked version of css.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach doesn’t need to change. Just use [Extract Text](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) plugin to save out the CSS files. You’ll need to make [multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) to create multiple CSS files.

OR

More ideally, (the approach I would take) make your CSS switch based on a different html or body class and just change the class. It won’t add much overhead, and it will be a more ideal UX when changing themes.

Comment: Simpler approach. But it will be harder to manage if you're too specific with your styling and amount of lines you have.

Comment: Your second link is dead. Error is: `The webpack 1.x documentation was deleted.`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a [combination of webpacks `style-loader` and `file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#simple-api) (second example ) and use [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) (second example "dynamic imports") to accomplish this:

```
function switchTheme(name) {
    // Remove the current theme stylesheet
    // Note: it is important that your theme css always is the last
    // <link/> tag within the <head/>
    $('head link[rel="stylesheet"]').last().remove();

    // Since webpack needs all filePaths at build-time
    // you can't dynamically build the filePath
    switch(name) {
        case 'red':
            // With require.ensure, it is possible to tell webpack
            // to only load the module (css) when require is actually called
            return require.ensure([], function () {
                require('style-loader/url!file-loader!styles/themes/red.css');
            });
        case 'yellow':
            return require.ensure([], function () {
                require('style-loader/url!file-loader!styles/themes/yellow.css');
            });
        case 'blue':
            return require.ensure([], function () {
                require('style-loader/url!file-loader!styles/themes/blue.css');
            });
        default:
            throw new Error('Unknown theme "' + name + '"');
    }
}
```

Then a call like `switchTheme('blue')` should do the trick.

And you might have to check your current `webpack.config.js`, in case you already have configured a loader for `.css` files.